# $[X,Y]=0 \implies \exp(X+Y)=\exp(X)\exp(Y)$

Tags: lie-groups

I am trying to show that if $[X,Y]=0$ then the exponential map $\exp : Lie(G)\to G$ is such that
$$\exp(X+Y)=\exp(X)\exp(Y), \forall X,Y\in Lie(G).$$
The hint is to show that $\gamma : t\mapsto \exp(tX)\exp(tY)$ is a one-parameter subgroup, which I can show :
\begin{align}
\gamma(t+s)=&\exp((t+s)X)\exp((t+s)Y)\\
=&\exp(tX)\exp(sX)\exp(tY)\exp(sY)\\
=&\exp(tX)\exp(tY)\exp(sX)\exp(sY)\\
=&\gamma(t)\gamma(s)
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
(\gamma(t))^{-1}&=(\exp(tX)\exp(tY))^{-1}\\
&=\exp(tY)^{-1}\exp(tX)^{-1}\\
&=\exp(-tY)\exp(-tX)\\
&=\exp(-tX)\exp(-tY)\\
&=\gamma(-t)
\end{align}

Note I used a result of a previous exercise that says that $[X,Y]=0$ iff $\exp(tX)\exp(sY)=\exp(sY)\exp(tX), \forall s,t \in \mathbb{R}$

But how to use that $\gamma$ is a one parameter subgroup to conclude?

Comment: Do one-parameter subgroups have special properties ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two Hints:

1. Observe that all the one-parameter subroup are linked with the exponential map (how?)
2. Recall that the differential of the group multiplication act like the sum, i.e.

$$
   d_{(e,e)}(\cdot)((v, w)) = v + w
$$

where we identify $T_{(e,e)}(G \times G) = T_e G \times T_e G$.

I will upgrade this hints to a full proof once you solved the problem

Comment: $\gamma : \mathbb{R}\to G$ is a one parameter subgroup so we know $\gamma(t)=exp(tZ)$ for some $Z\in Lie(G)$. Then get $exp(tX)exp(tY)=exp(tZ)\forall t$, so in particular $exp(X)exp(Y)=exp(Z)$ that we can rewrite $\mu(exp(X),exp(Y))=expt(Z)$ where $\mu : G \times G \to G$ is the multiplication map and then I understand that using point 2. you will get the result. But I am kind of struggeling to write down the last steps in a nice way(note we defined Lie(G) to be the left invariant vector fields).

Comment: recall that every one parameter subgroup is the integral curve passing from $e$ of a vector field $X \in \mathrm{Lie}(G)$. It is a known fact that two vector field in $\mathrm{Lie}(G)$ are equal if and only if are equal in $e$.

To conclude you just need to differentiate the curves $\mathrm{exp}(tX) \cdot \mathrm{exp}(tY)$ and $\mathrm{exp}(tZ)$ in $0$. You get $X_e + Y_e = Z_e$ that implies $X + Y = Z$

Comment: Okay, I see. I just had some trouble because I am not at ease when I work with the isomorphism $T_eG\times T_e G \cong T_{(e,e)}G$.